# In Ruby YARD docs, what it mean to wrap a word +example+ with + (plus sign)?

Tags: ruby, yard

In the [official YARD docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/Tags.md), there is the following example:

```
# @overload set(key, value)
#   Sets a value on key
#   @param key [Symbol] describe key param
#   @param value [Object] describe value param
# @overload set(value)
#   Sets a value on the default key +:foo+
#   @param value [Object] describe value param
def set(*args) end
```

What special meaning does `+:foo+` have when it is wrapped with `+` on either side? Does `+:foo+` have a different meaning from `:foo`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It has no meaning to YARD. In fact, YARD doesn't care about markup *at all*, it simply passes the string through to the output generator tool unprocessed. (With some limited exceptions, e.g. support for references to modules, classes, methods.)

It *does*, however, have meaning to SimpleMarkup / RDoc (which is one of the output processors YARD supports). `+foo+` is RDoc's syntax for code highlighting, i.e. it is equivalent to `` `foo` `` in Markdown.

So the difference is that `:foo` is rendered as ":foo" whereas `+:foo+` is rendered as "`:foo`", assuming that you use SimpleMarkup / RDoc as the output processor. If you use Markdown as the output processor, it doesn't mean anything at all.